# Are there any "smart" Pull Request diff plugins for BitBucket

Tags: github, version-control, diff, pull-request, bitbucket-server

I'm wondering if there any plugins for Bitbucket that allow you to filter out certain kinds of changes from the diffs?   What I have in mind would probably need to be "sensitive" to the coding language

There's a wide plethora of things I wish I could (dynamically) choose to exclude including:

- Inserting a "final" keyword in Java
- Changes to comments
- Splitting or combining lines (nominally a "whitespace" change, but not recognized as such by most diff utilities)
- Reordered Java imports
- Any changes to Java imports
- Moving entire methods or field declarations (without changing them)
- Almost any change that where the "new" is semantically equivalent to the "old"

Now folks, I hope we aren't going to get get into a debates about whether or not ignoring such diffs is a good idea.    What I would like to see is a filter where these things can be turned on and off.   Not any sort of permanent and fixed suppression of such things.

I would argue that sometimes/often it is handy for the diffs to focus in on "the semantic" changes.

My specific needs is for Bitbucket pull requests, but I'm kinda interested to hear about such things for any "diff" utility, including general utilities not specific to Bitbucket, nor even pull requests.